# BIRT Report Generation - How do I keep all row data?

Tags: java, spring, birt

My question has to do with the output that is generated when I run a BIRT report.

Normally, a BIRT report would *not* show the duplicate portion of each row of data that is written to a report.  For instance, if I were generating a report that were to contain multiple lines (rows) of data and the data was organized by a 'Group ID'.  The data, for each specific Group ID would be shown indented and organized by each Group ID.  The Group ID would be shown in the first row of output, but for subsequent rows of data (for that same Group ID), the Group ID would not be shown.  In otherwords, no need to display the same Group ID over and over in the report.  This method helps to keep the clutter down and makes the report easier to read.

I have a customer who *doesn't* want the report generated this way.  The specifications are to show each row of report data as if it were directly from a SQL query.

Is there a way to have the BIRT report show *all data* during the report generation?  I've looked all over and still haven't come up with any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption 'Normally, ...' is wrong. Instead, normally BIRT *does* output each row of report data as if it were directly from a SQL query.

If you create a group and you *don't* want to repeat the same values, you have to move those columns to the group header (and use "drop cell: detail", if you like).

However, for the *columns*, there's also a property called "suppress duplicates" or so. Maybe this is set in your template or style sheet or you checked it accidentally?

Make sure this is not checked!

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I would like to understand how to use this feature of BIRT, but I am still confused even after trying to reorganize my data columns.  I think you are telling me to reorganize my columns data in my DataCube... Is that correct?  The way I have it organized now is that each column is shown indented under the one before it and everything is in the same Group.  I tried creating a new Group for each column and that essentially, gives me the same results.  Please elaborate so that I can understand this concept.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use data cubes and thus I can't help you. You should have mentioned in your question that you are using a data cube. I assumed you were using a table item.

Comment: Your suggestion, ultimately, forced me to try a different approach to solving this problem.  Instead of using a DataCube and a CrossTab to display the results of the query, I inserted and built a table.  The table gave me the function that my customer required.  It took me some time to learn, but I believe I am outputting my data correctly now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use  ROW_NUMBER() in your SQL to create a unique value, each row will now be different and will display.  Include the field in your report, but don't display it (hide).

This should give you the desired results.

Comment: Thanks for this reply.  I did exactly what you suggested and it worked.  I now have each row displayed in the report.  However, Subtotals are not working as I would have hoped.  Each row in the report is subtotaled.  I am not able to correctly arrive at the correct subtotal that I am looking for.  I am still working to provide a correct subtotal.  Thank you!

Comment: Still looking for a solution... When I add the Unique Row Number (and subsequently hide it) to the report, I do see each line of output in the report.  This part is good, However, subtotaling isn't correct.  To use the BIRT subtotal (and grand total features) the data items that I am totaling need to be defined as a Summary Field (Measure) in the Data Cube.  When I build the report this way (using the Row_Number() feature), I get subtotals on each and every row out data in the report (not on the grouping that I requested the subtotal to be calculated).  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The Row_Number() function was useful for forcing each line of output to be unique (and to be displayed).  The subtotals function, however, wasn't working at all after displaying the data this way.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: did you use a new aggregation tool from the palette to get your subtotals?